# Extending Overrides

Tags: typescript, overriding

In TypeScript, I have a class that extends the module `Events` which has the following in its declaration:

```
on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;
```

The class that extends the module emits a number of events that have different signatures for the listener. I can create multiple overrides for this property that a slightly more specific, but still match the signature. Something like:

```
export class Agent extends Events {
  constructor(conf: IAgentConf);
  on(event: 'eventA', listener: (body: IAEvent) => void): this
  on(event: 'eventB', listener: (body: IPayload<IBEvent>) => void):this;
  on(event: 'eventC', listener: (body: ICEvent[]) => void): this;
  ...
}
```

Using this typings, TypeScript can identify the shape of the callback when declaring the event listeners.

However, I'm running into problems when I go to extend this object further, with a new object that emits a new event:

```
class MyAgent extends Agent {
  static EventD: string = 'EventD';
  init: () => void;
  on(event: 'EventD', listener: (body: IEventD) => void):this;
  constructor(conf: IAgentConf) {
    super(conf);

    this.init = () => {
      this.on('EventA', body => {
        this.emit(MyAgent.EventD, body.thingy);
      });
    };

    init();
  }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work. I get the error:

```
(TS) Property 'on' in type 'MyAgent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Agent'.
```

Is it possible to *further* override a property from a grandparent class in the grandchild class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a subclass can override a property (or method) of the superclass as long as the subclass's property is assignable to the parent class's property.  For a method with multiple call signatures, I believe the rule is that each call signature in the superclass must have a corresponding call signature in the subclass that is assignable to it.  This "assignable" relation is a little muddy because [the parameters are compared bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).

For the methods to be compatible in your case, every class needs to redeclare all the event types from the superclasses as well as the general call signature:

```
class Agent extends Events {
  on(event: 'eventA', listener: (body: IAEvent) => void): this
  on(event: 'eventB', listener: (body: IPayload<IBEvent>) => void):this;
  on(event: 'eventC', listener: (body: ICEvent[]) => void): this;
  on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;
  on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this { 
    return super.on(event, listener);
  }
}
class MyAgent extends Agent {
  on(event: 'eventA', listener: (body: IAEvent) => void): this
  on(event: 'eventB', listener: (body: IPayload<IBEvent>) => void):this;
  on(event: 'eventC', listener: (body: ICEvent[]) => void): this;
  on(event: 'EventD', listener: (body: IEventD) => void):this;
  on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;
  on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this { 
    return super.on(event, listener);
  }
}
```

You can cut down the duplication a bit by defining an interface just for the `on` method and extending it:

```
interface EventsOn<This> { 
  (event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): This;
}
class Events {
  on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {
    // ...
    return this;
  }
}
interface AgentOn<This> extends EventsOn<This> { 
  (event: 'eventA', listener: (body: IAEvent) => void): This;
  (event: 'eventB', listener: (body: IPayload<IBEvent>) => void):This;
  (event: 'eventC', listener: (body: ICEvent[]) => void): This;
}
interface Agent {
  on: AgentOn<this>;
}
class Agent extends Events { }
interface MyAgentOn<This> extends AgentOn<This> { 
  (event: 'EventD', listener: (body: IEventD) => void):This;
}
interface MyAgent { 
  on: MyAgentOn<this>;
}
class MyAgent extends Agent { }
```

(When you declare an interface for a function type with call signatures, extending the interface seems to accumulate the call signatures, whereas when you declare an interface with an `on` method, extending the interface seems to lose the call signatures from the superinterface.)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. It solved my immediate problem. I'll wait until tomorrow before marking it as the accepted answer.